# Biometric fingerprint reader not recognized on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, fingerprint, biometrics

I bought a fingerprint reader to equip 10 workstations on Windows 10 in a small company.

It's this one "Benss Fingerprint Reader for Windows 10, Windows Hello Fingerprint USB Security Key, 360 Degree Speedy Correspondent, WQHL Certified"

They all work except on two stations.
It's very weird because all the workstations are identical, exactly the same components (same motherboard, etc.).

I've tried a lot of things and I'm going crazy: I activated GPO biometrics with the same way, I checked and it's ok.
I downloaded the drivers from the BENSS site but they don't work.
I run sfc /scannow
I launched DISM.exe / Online / Cleanup-Image / RestoreHeath
I try to modify local gpedit.msc to activate Biometric, etc.

Nothing works and I think I will end up reinstalling the computers completely, but that does not suit me at all ...

On the other 8 workstations, I plugged in and the player worked immediately without doing anything.
All workstations are on Windows 20H2 19042.630

Here's a screenshot when it's ok:

[image]

Here's a screenshot when it doesn't ok:

[image]

Here are the drivers used when it works:

[image]

I noticed that EngineAdapter.dll was present on the friends where it works:

[image]

On the other hand it is missing in WindBioPlugins on the two stations where it does not work:

[image]

Does someone have an idea ?
Is there a way to correctly reinstall this WindBioPlugins directory?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I have this [same fingerprint reader](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073Z7FGKV) with Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview (Version 2004) and I also had issues at first. Windows said it was setting up the device when I plugged it in, but it never got it working on any USB ports. Like you, I went to the Benss website for the drivers to install manually, but the only driver package they had didn't seem to do anything. Windows Hello said I didn't have a fingerprint reader and Device Manager said the device couldn't start, so the drivers wouldn't actually install.

I finally got it to work by going into Windows Updates and checking for additional updates. Lo and behold, there was one driver update for ELAN Finger Print - Biometric. I took the update and since I still had the Device Manager open, I could see that it immediately fixed the issue and showed the fingerprint reader as available. Windows Hello agreed that it was ready and I was able to start adding my fingerprints. It's been working well for a few months.

Given that it's been a few months, you may have already reinstalled Windows, but I hope this can help someone who comes across this question.

Comment: Additionally after installing that driver from Windows Update it still didn't work. I had to remove de device from Device Manager, unplug it, plug it back, install drivers from Windows Update again and THEN it got recognized!